# How to add an application shortcut but not display on the start menu

Tags: install4j

I need to have a shortcut to my application that has command line options pre-configured.  This would only be used for troubleshooting so I don't want it "easily" found by a user.  My thought was to create a shortcut in the program directory during install.  This shortcut would not be on the start menu.  During troubleshooting, the user would navigate to the program directory and double click on the shortcut thus invoking the program with the debugging options.

Is there a way using Install4j actions to create an application shortcut that is NOT on the start menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a "Create start menu entry" action by setting the "Entry name" property to an absolute path name, like:

```
${installer:sys.installationDir}/Debug Launcher link
```

You can replace "Debug Launcher link" with a path in your installation directory.